# Android NullPointerException in fragment with Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, adapter

I'm developing an app based on the One activity - multiple fragments pattern. In this case I'm use retrofit to get a list of objects from the api and now I want to put these in a Listview inside the fragment. I'm working with an adapter to "fill" this Listview.

The app crashes after the succes() call. This is the short log:

```
4-13 19:01:30.647    1968-1968/com.plusplus.i.jongerenparticipatieplatfrom E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.plusplus.i.jongerenparticipatieplatfrom, PID: 1968
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
        at com.plusplus.i.jongerenparticipatieplatfrom.adapter.DmsAdapter.getView(DmsAdapter.java:58)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)...`
```

I guess something is wrong because I do everything inside the OnCreateView() method.

Here is the code:

```
public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment implements Callback<List<DtoDms>> {
    private DmsAdapter dmsAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dmsAdapter = new DmsAdapter(getActivity());
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);

        ListView listView  = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dmsList);
        listView.setAdapter(dmsAdapter);
        View emptyView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
        listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        getJppService().getOpenDms(1, this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void success(List<DtoDms> dtoDmses, Response response) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ok dit werkt al", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dmsAdapter.setOpenDms(dtoDmses);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the adapter class

```
public class DmsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final Context context;
private List<DtoDms> openDms;

public DmsAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.openDms = new ArrayList();
}

public void setOpenDms(List<DtoDms> openDms) {
    this.openDms = openDms;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return openDms.size();
}

@Override
public DtoDms getItem(int position) {
    return openDms.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final DtoDms dms = getItem(position);
     ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView != null) {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = from(context).inflate(R.layout.dms_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
  //  viewHolder.dateTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dms.getEndDate()));
    viewHolder.questionTextView.setText(dms.getQuestion());
    viewHolder.extraTextView.setText(dms.getExtraInfo());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView dateTextView;
    TextView questionTextView;
    TextView extraTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
   //     dateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dmsDate);
        questionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dmsQuestion);
        extraTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dmsExtra);
    }
}
```

}

Edit 2: Breakpoint in success says context is not null:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUnfG.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that the NullPointer takes place in your DmsAdapter class (line 58). Please post more code =)

Comment: Could you show your DmsAdapter class?

Comment: I added the code to the issue

Comment: The line convertView = from(context).inflate(R.layout.dms_item, parent, false); doesn't make sense to me.  Where is your from(Context context) implementation - or is this a call to LayoutInflater.from(Context context)?

Comment: @MichaelKrause this is a call to LayoutInflator.from yes

Comment: On what version of Android is the error occurring?

Comment: @MichaelKrause working in API 19

Comment: I'm guessing the context you've passed to LayoutInflater.from(Context context) must be null.  I'm not sure how based on the code you've posted, though.

Comment: @MichaelKrause I added a picture where you can see it isn't null

Comment: I'd guess something is wrong with the from(context). call, it would be nice to see the code for that.  I'd suggest putting this in your constructor and use the the saved inflater in your getView() `mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Comment: Which is your line 58 in DmsAdapter.java?

Comment: @songchenwen it's this line: convertView = from(context).inflate(R.layout.dms_item, parent, false);

Comment: Try edit this line like this. convertView = from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dms_item, parent, false);

Comment: @songchenwen now he gives nullpointer at viewHolder.questionTextView.setText(dms.getQuestion());

Comment: This means you don't have a TextView with id dmsQuestion in R.layout.dms_item. BTW, @MichaelKrause was right, your context is null. Another problem in your code is that you can't just assign this.openDms with another List and call notifyDataSetChanged. You need to modify the list, not replace it. Change this.openDms type to ArrayList and use the clear and addAll method.

Comment: I do have a textview with that id in dms_item. With the suggestion you made (parent.getContext) the convertView isn't null anymore but gives the Nullpointer somewhere else

Comment: Please paste your error log here. And mention me in your next comment.

Comment: @songchenwen `Process: com.plusplus.i.jongerenparticipatieplatfrom, PID: 1392
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.plusplus.i.jongerenparticipatieplatfrom.adapter.DmsAdapter.getView(DmsAdapter.java:65)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)`

Comment: questionTextView is null, which can only happen when your view can't find such id.

Comment: I don't think the posted code is telling the whole story as I don't think it is the exact code that was run when this exception was thrown.  The code as posted won't compile.  It is clearly blowing up in LayoutInflater.from with a NullPointerException.  I've looked back through various releases of the LayoutInflater.java code and the only thing I can determine that would throw a NPE is the line that references the passed in Context.

Comment: @MichaelKrause it returns a NPE because the `questionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dmsQuestion);
        extraTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dmsExtra);` both return null, so it crashes when trying to set the text. I just can't understand why it can't find the view.

Comment: Are you supporting multiple display formats?  In other words, do you have a layout file with the same name in different layout folders where one of them has the view defined and the other does not?

Comment: @MichaelKrause Damn this is the answer. Android studio made a folder layout-v17 with also a dms_item.xml (not the correct one). I had something to do with the min api I guess. It works now, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad we finally got to the root cause!  :)